# how to remove a table row by a button?

Tags: php, forms

I have created a form in which we can add multiple rows by click on a button. but I dont't know how to delete that rows.

The Code:

```
<form>
   <table>
    <?php
      for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
        $inst_no = $i+1;
       // Display only the first line
       if ($nbr_ligne == 0) $nbr_ligne = 1;
       if ($i >= $nbr_ligne) $display = 'style="display:none"';

         echo '
       <tr id="cell'.$i.'" '.$display.'>
       <td align="center"><b>'.$inst_no.'</b><br>&nbsp;</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="total_balance[]" id="total_balance'.$i.'" class="payment_text_box" /><br>
       <input type="button" value="Add Installment" class="installment_button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(\'cell'.($i+1).'\').style.display=\'table-row\'; this.style.display=\'none\'" />
       </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="installment_amount[]" id="installment_amount'.$i.'" class="payment_text_box"/><br>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="remaining_balance[]" id="remaining_balance'.$i.'" class="payment_text_box" /><br>
        <input name="submit" type="button" value="Remove Installment" class="installment_button" onclick="remove();" />
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="installment_date[]" id="installment_date'.$i.'" class="payment_text_box"/><br>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>';
      }
        ?>
</table>
</form>
```

Please tell me what is the way to remove that rows?

Comment: please be more specific.

Comment: There are several ways to remove a row. Please clarify whether you want to remove the row client-side (Javascript) or server-side (PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ithink this is use for how to add and remove table row by button.
http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tableaddrow.html

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript remove() function add the something like the following (untested):

```
thisItem.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(thisItem.parentNode.parentNode);
```